# List all blogs in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

How can I list all blogs available in my Orchard CMS installation? I would like to simply display a navigation to all my blogs on the home page but there does not seem to be any easy way to achieve this within the Admin UI, especially since `Blog` is not a `Content` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blog *is* a content type. Just do a projection filtered by the type blog, and you're done.